# Reporting error on calling memcpy

Tags: c

How can I make sure that if someone uses come specific function(say memcpy) in code, then it returns an error.

We have removed all the instances of memcpy from code with some internal designed function,

what I want to make sure is that whenever someone uses memcpy in future, the compiler throws an errors msg.

Comment: You have two good answers, but I'm curious why you want to ban memcpy? It's a pretty simple function and should be hard to get wrong.

Comment: if you use GCC, then add `#pragma GCC poison memcpy` in you main head file, it may help you

Comment: to overcome the problem of overlap, yes we can use memmove but they dont use it...i dont know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the preprocessor for this, like

```
#define memcpy(a, b, c) do_not_use_memcpy
```

Put that in a header file that is included in all source files, and the preprocessor will replace all calls to `memcpy` with the (undefined) symbol `do_not_use_memcpy`. As that symbol is undefined, you will get a compiler error about it.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the newly created function uses memcpy internally.

Comment: +1 particularly nice in that it will give you a readable compiler warning containing the text "do_not_use_memcpy"

Comment: @Sohrab Ahmad, undef and re-def it in the new function.

Comment: @SohrabAhmad For that single place, undefine the macro with `#undef memcpy`.

Comment: It's sound dangerous to me because gcc may replace some loops to a call to the memcpy function. This is done through the tree-loop-distribute-patterns optimization in gcc 4.8.

Comment: @Maxime The code optimizations are done long after the preprocessor has run, so that won't be a problem. This doesn't actually replace the actual `memcpy` function, just changes the calls to it.

Comment: I see, but are you sure there won't be any call to the memcpy at the end? What about adding a `-fno-builtin-memcpy`?

Comment: @Maxime If that macro is in all translation units, then there won't be any explicit calls to `memcpy`. That flag just tells GCC that it should not use its own implementation of `memcpy`, and instead use the one in the standard library.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid breaking libraries, use the `deprecated` attribute :

```
void * my_new_memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num )
{
    return memcpy(destination, source, num);
} __attribute__((deprecated));

// Make sure this is used *after* declaring the function
#define memcpy my_new_memcpy
```

Comment: What about using "-Wl,-wrap,memcpy" instead?

Comment: @Maxime Not sure: that's a linker argument while the `__attribute__((deprecated))` is (iirc) interpreted by the compiler.

Comment: I meant, instead of using the `#define` but still using the deprecated attribute (I don't know if possible though).

Comment: @Maxime I knew you meant that :-) But you can't, because `deprecated` is interpreted in the compilation phase which goes before the linking phase (which is where your argument runs).